# JSONArray in JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I need to create a JSONArray object which is inside another JSONArray. 
[This is the json that I have to parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzXpa.png)

I need to access the title, id, and image_url in the photo array which is inside the photos array

Below is the code I have tried.

```
 private static List<ImagelistActivity> extractFeatureFromJson(String flickrJSON) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(flickrJSON)) {
        return null;
    }
    List<ImagelistActivity> images = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(flickrJSON);
        JSONObject photos = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("photos");
        JSONArray photo = photos.getJSONArray("photo");

        for (int i = 0; i < photo.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject currentImage = photo.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = currentImage.getString("id");

            String url = currentImage.getString("url_s");

            String title = currentImage.getString("title");

            ImagelistActivity img = new ImagelistActivity(id, title, url);

            images.add(img);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        .
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the Image JSON results", e);
    }


    return images;
}
```

But this does not work

> org.json.JSONException: No value for photo

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: Problem parsing the Image JSON results  org.json.JSONException: No value for photo                                                                                                             This is the error I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is formatted in this heirarchy:

Photos > Photo

So first, you would have to get the JSONObject Photos then from there get the Photo array.
e.g.

```
...
JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(flickrJSON);
JSONObject photos = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("photos");
JSONArray photo = photos.getJSONArray("photo");
...
```

**EDIT**

For your new code, the error is, some JSON objects from the JSON array doesn't have a key for the url_s

```
{
    "id": "30847132948",
    "owner": "140768897@N07",
    "secret": "2e224eedf8",
    "server": "1892",
    "farm": 2,
    "title": "Missouri Lawmakers Pass Computer Science...",
    "ispublic": 1,
    "isfriend": 0,
    "isfamily": 0
}
```

So, it would be better if you could check first if the JSONObject has a key named url_s

## TL;DR

```
for (int i = 0; i < photo.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject currentImage = photo.getJSONObject(i);
    if (currentImage.has("url_s")) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: not working, got the following error                                                                            Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results  org.json.JSONException: No value for url_s.

Comment: That means my code works and answered your question, what you now have is another error, which is parsing url_s. Could you post the whole json as a string here so i could help further. A possible reason may be that url_s is not of type String.

Comment: This is the url of the api:      https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=6f102c62f41998d151e5a1b48713cf13&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_s

Comment: Thats weird, could you edit your question with your new code so i could follow. The url_s data type is string.

Comment: I have edited the question with my new code

Comment: Now the error is gone, but nothing is displayed in the screen. A blank screen is appeared.

Comment: Could you print the size of images before returning the images from the function and show if its blank here.

Log.d("images size", "" + images.size());

Comment: It prints 100 as the images size

Comment: Then its now good to go, the problem now is on how you are showing these images on your activity. The parsing of images is now complete.

Comment: This is my project link. https://github.com/sivaperumal644/Gallery  If possible can you check where I have made my mistake

Comment: I dont know where you have read your code from but, its kind'a messy. What you did wrong was using the adapter to update your list. What you should be doing is create a List(ArrayList) that will hold the values, then change everything on your code where you used mAdapter to modify the values as that list. Then each time you add, edit, or delete items from the list, call the adapters notify data set changed method.

Comment: Now its working, had some small problems in the default_layout.xml. Thank for your help

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the raw data. You only have one array called photo.

```
{"photos"{... 
  ... 
   "photo": [...
```

You missed the top object key of `photos` in the base response before you get the array.

By the way, I would suggest using an API that's already handled this logic for you. E.g https://github.com/boncey/Flickr4Java

Comment: Can you explain me how to create object for photos array and photo array.

Comment: `getJSONObject("photos")`... This is not an array, it's an object

Answer (score 0):

Sack off the manual way...

Use jackson and make a POJO that represents the data. You can use an online service to make the POJO/Class code for you from the JSON and annotate it as @Data.

You can then use ObjectMapper to parse the json->POJO or POJO -> json.

[A JSON to POJO using Jackson converter](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

[Object Mapper Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Comment: Great suggestion but you are not really helping him to learn. Also, GSON is better than Jackson. If you see a beginner, teach him what he knows not more of what he doesn't.